# how to update 5 text views with data going from one to the next

Tags: android, variables, textview

thanks for checking out this Q and i hope u can help

i have 5 TextViews that need to diplay what the last 5 spins are.
but only `lastSpinView.setText(lastSpin);` and `lastSpin2View.setText(lastSpin2);` work properly.
`setLast4()` seems to make `lastSpin3View.setText(lastSpin3);` `lastSpin4View.setText(lastSpin4);` `lastSpin5View.setText(lastSpin5);` duplicate the value of `lastSpin2View.setText(lastSpin2)` im sure the problem is at setLast4() but carnt think of how to fix it

```
public void checkResult(){
    coinResult1();
    coinResult2();
    coinResult = coinresult1 + coinresult2;
    if (coinResult == playerSelection){
        playerWins();
        buttonsReset();
        setLastSpin();
    }
    else {
        playerLost();
        buttonsReset();
        setLastSpin();
    }
   }

   public void playerWins(){
        TextView winner = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winlose);
        TextView cashView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playerCash);
        playerCash = playerCash + (playerBet * playerBonus);
        playerWinLoss = playerBet * playerBonus;
        winner.setText("You Won " + "$" + String.valueOf(playerWinLoss));
        cashView.setText("$" + String.valueOf(playerCash));
   }

   public void playerLost(){
    TextView lost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winlose);
        TextView cashView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playerCash);
        playerCash = playerCash - (playerBet);

        lost.setText("You Lost " + "$" + String.valueOf(playerBet));
        cashView2.setText("$" + String.valueOf(playerCash));
   }

    public void setLastSpin(){
        if (coinResult == 0){
            lastSpin = "HH";

        }
        else if (coinResult == 1){
            lastSpin = "HT";
        }
        else if (coinResult == 2){
            lastSpin = "TT";
        }

        showLastSpin();
        setLast4();
    }

    public void showLastSpin(){
        TextView lastSpinView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2); 
        TextView lastSpin2View = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3); 
        TextView lastSpin3View = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4); 
        TextView lastSpin4View = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5); 
        TextView lastSpin5View = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6); 


        lastSpinView.setText(lastSpin);
        lastSpin2View.setText(lastSpin2);
        lastSpin3View.setText(lastSpin3);
        lastSpin4View.setText(lastSpin4);
        lastSpin5View.setText(lastSpin5);
    }

    public void setLast4(){
        lastSpin2 = lastSpin;
        lastSpin3 = lastSpin2;
        lastSpin4 = lastSpin3;
        lastSpin5 = lastSpin4;
    }
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Didn't you mistake the order of `showLastSpin(); setLast4();` because as it is you first show the values in the textView and then you change the value --> the textView text doesn't change so.
Can you show the initialization of all of your variable lastSpin ?

Comment: @clad when i only try and display 2 results it works, on the first click TV1 displays the result and TV2 shows nothing as it should, and when i click over and over Tv1 always shows the last result and TV2 always shows the second last result. which is fine, but when i add 3 more TV's they show the second result, its bad coding but i carnt think of how to get the 3rd, 4th and 5th results to show properly

Comment: Yes but that doesn't mean it's the good way to do it ;)
Can you show the creation of lastSpin, lastSpin2 etc...

As you do it now, you change the value of the textView first (so at that time it may work because you already have the correct values in lastSpin and lastSpin2) and then you change for the next call, is this was you want to do ?

And by the way you should use array in order to have a more clear code ;)

Comment: they should be an array?

Comment: all i want is 5 textviews that the results moves from the first to last view so that the first result is at the top then a button is pressed and the first result moves to TV2 and the new result is displayed at TV1 then the button is pressed again and result 1 n 2 both move to TV2 and TV3 and Tv1 now show the new result and so on...the other code doesnt apply its just the ones i posted checkResult() starts the problem code setLastSpin

Comment: So like I said at the beginning try to invert the two lines
`showLastSpin(); setLast4();`--> `setLast4(); showLastSpin();`

Comment: sorry its late where i am and have had little sleep, ill go try now

Comment: nope it just updates all textViews

Comment: its accually worse then before as TV1 and Tv2 arnt working now

Answer (score 0):

I think you just inverted two lines. What you want to do is :

1. Get the new value in a variable
2. Move the different values one line down (in the lastSpin(s) )
3. Update the view

   ```
   public void setLastSpin(){
       String newValue = "";
       if (coinResult == 0)
           newValue = "HH";
       else if (coinResult == 1)
           newValue = "HT";
       else if (coinResult == 2)
           newValue = "TT";

       setLast4();
       lastSpin = newValue;
       showLastSpin();
   }

   public void setLast4(){
        lastSpin2 = lastSpin;
   }

   public void showLastSpin(){
        TextView lastSpinView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2); 
        TextView lastSpin2View = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3); 

        lastSpinView.setText(lastSpin);
        lastSpin2View.setText(lastSpin2);
   }
   ```

The problem of what you did is that you overwrite the lastSpin value and change the local value after changing the view according to it

And also for this

```
  public void setLast4(){
        lastSpin2 = lastSpin;
        lastSpin3 = lastSpin2;
        lastSpin4 = lastSpin3;
        lastSpin5 = lastSpin4;
    }
```

You have to do it in reverse otherwise you lose the values everytimes. You put lastSpin in LastSpin2 and then lastSpin2 to lastSpin3 --> it's like you put lastSpin to lastSpin3 directly etc.

So it should be something like

```
  public void setLast4(){
        lastSpin5 = lastSpin4;
        lastSpin4 = lastSpin3;
        lastSpin3 = lastSpin2;
        lastSpin2 = lastSpin;
    }
```

All of this is considering that lastSpin is the TV1 containing the last score of course.

Hope it will solve your problem ;)

Comment: thanks        public void setLast4(){
        lastSpin5 = lastSpin4;
        lastSpin4 = lastSpin3;
        lastSpin3 = lastSpin2;
        lastSpin2 = lastSpin;
    }  was the only thing i changed and now it works perfect thank you Clad

Comment: I think you will need also the other changes but it's good if it's work ;) don't forget to validate the answer ;)